# OSWORKFLOW integration with spring

Tags: java, spring, dtd, osworkflow, xml

I am trying to initialize workflow with spring. For that i have added workflow_2.8.2.jar and as for my workflow descriptor i am simply using my localhost to store its dtd.
Now, when i am trying to initialize workflow it gives me an error which seen confusing to me right now.

```
    "com.opensymphony.workflow.FactoryException: Error in workflow descriptor: file:/home/fhl04/development/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/TestingPersistenceUsingSpring/WEB-INF/classes/descriptor.xml: root cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd"
```

and even i am not using "http://opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd" as it is now available in my localhost.

And just to add more information the code runs perfect if it is not been initialized by spring(osworkflow_2.7.0.jar used).

I dont know where i am going wrong and what am i missing..?
Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its too late to answer this question though, but the issue was that inside the api their were restrictions on using the dtd which had previous URL. So after changing the URL of the dtd inside the api it works perfect..!

Answer (score 0):

You say "I am not using "http://opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd" as it is now available in my localhost."  To solve your problem, try proving to yourself that this statement is true.  Or, if you are already too convinced of its truth for that to be a useful exercise, imagine you are proving it to me.  I start from the position that you *are* still using it.  (If you're not using it, why is Java trying to fetch it?  Case closed.)  Ask: does your software know that you're not using it?  Do all the XML documents that might have document type declarations know about the local copy of the DTD?

Note in particular that the XML document whose URI is given as `file:/home/fhl04/development/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/TestingPersistenceUsingSpring/WEB-INF/classes/descriptor.xml` seems (judging by the error message) not to know about the local copy of the DTD.